# Cloud9 real-time collaboration tools in local server?

Tags: real-time, cloud9-ide

Cloning the git repo using the instruction here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9#readme
I don't see any of the real-time tools currently implemented on c9.io hosted site.

Does anyone know where the new tools are?

Answer (score 0):

The collaboration tools are currently not available in the open source version of Cloud9.